# Insert section with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some js code that will insert a section tag when a button is clicked . I would like for some content to be in the section tag when its inserted. Preferable this would happen on the same button click.

HTML (Working) :

```
<button a onclick="runme()">New Slide</button>
```

JS (Working) :

```
 function runme()
{

    var sec = document.createElement("section");
    document.getElementById('slides').appendChild(sec);
}
```

**Code to be added to section tag**:

```
<b>Title</b><br><br>

                    <small>
                        <ul>
                            <li></li><br>
                            <li></li><br>
                            <li></li><br>
                            <li></li><br>
                            <li></li><br>
                            <li></li><br>
                            <li></li><br>
                        </ul>
                    </small>

                <br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/84nvqzuj/) here

```
   function runme()
  {
     var sec = document.createElement("section");
     sec.innerHTML = '<b>Title</b><br><br> <small> <ul>  <li></li><br><li></li><br><li></li><br><li></li><br><li></li><br><li></li><br><li></li><br> </ul></small><br>';
     document.getElementById('slides').appendChild(sec);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create every single node and append it to yor "sec" variable. 
You can also use the **innerHTML** property and just write your HTML code in the variable. If you only want to add text, you can use the property **textContent** istead of **innerHTML**.

```
sec.innerHTML = "<div>content of the <i>section</i></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code you also can set the attribute that you want, like class attribute or id attribute:

```
 function runme()
 {
    var cont = "<b>Title</b><br><br> <small><ul><li></li><br><li></li><br><li></li><br><li></li><br><li></li><br><li></li><br><li></li><br></ul></small><br>"; 

    var sec = $('<section/>',{
                 class : 'hi'}).appendTo('body'); //<-- with additional attribute
    var sec = $('<section/>').appendTo('body'); //<-- without additional attribute

    $('section').html(cont);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the working code in the [bin](http://jsbin.com/cehetuwoga/2/edit). You have to use innerHTML to make this happen.